Email alert on CCP custom status (Unavailable) duration exceed 15 mins
I have a requirement to setup an alert on agent custom status duration/busy/unavialble.
For example if CCP has custom status (Busy/Unavailable) for more than 15 mins should send an alert email.
I have searched but could not find any documentation related to this. Any tips would  be great.
I already have email alerts setup for missed calls but unable to work out trigger for custom status of CCP.

tried rules for real time metrics with no luck

